# Vegetarian food in Dallas, TX?

Tags: food, traveling

My husband and I are traveling to Dallas, TX.  I wanted to ask how vegetarian-friendly the city is and whether there are any specific recommendations for vegetarian or vegetarian-friendly places to go.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for local advice, which is likely to be opinion-based and quickly go out of date, as well as being too broad of a question. See meta http://meta.vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/50/are-questions-asking-for-local-or-travel-advice-on-topic?cb=1 and please post there if you disagree :)

Comment: You may find this question helpful? [Is there a (social media?) website dedicated to helping people find veg\*n restaurants, shops and services?](//vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/363)

Comment: [Let me HappyCow that for you.](https://www.happycow.net/searchmap?lat=&lng=&location=Dallas%2C+Texas%2C+USA)

Comment: @Turion My apologies, too many tabs open and I posted in the wrong place. But answering in comments and links sending users elsewhere to get the information they asking about is also frowned upon, so just for future reference.